# What should we do with [arrayindexoutofboundsexception]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not quite sure what action we should take regarding the [arrayindexoutofboundsexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrayindexoutofboundsexception).

IMO we don't need a tag for such a [specific exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

It currently has no tag wiki, but luckily the tag name is quite specific. There are less than 50 questions of which all are [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) related, but I thought I would still ask the community first, before doing anything:

- Should the [arrayindexoutofboundsexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrayindexoutofboundsexception) tag be made a synonym of [indexoutofboundsexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception)?
- Should a tag wiki be written and then retag the [~600](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception+arrays) questions with both [indexoutofboundsexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception) and [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) to [arrayindexoutofboundsexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrayindexoutofboundsexception)
- Simply remove the tag?
- Do nothing?

Comment: You haven't provided any rationale for taking action on this tag.

Comment: It seems like [[tag:indexoutofboundsexception]] is actually the real [[tag:arrayindexoutofboundsexception]] tag as that's what its tag wiki refers to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I recall that overly specific tags are not the desired way to use the tag system. So that would by the rationale behind this question. If I'm wrong, please correct me

Comment: Note that [tag:arrayindexoutofbounds] is already a synonym for [tag:indexoutofboundsexception].

Comment: Such a waste of a burnination punny title :) "[arrayindexoutofboundsexception] is out of bounds". More on topic, the tag seems ok (at least it does not seem to be causing harm. That said, it could use a tag wiki and excerpt - please do help the tag out if you are an SME

Comment: Leads me to wonder just how long can a tag get? How many characters before the server revolts?

Comment: @user4581301 Tags can have up to 35 characters. Now, I'm unsure if the length of said 35 characters determines anything, perhaps we can take advantage of very wide Unicode characters. Perhaps not.

Comment: In Java ... there are 3 exceptions: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  The first is the supertype of the others.  Therefore ... they are not (strictly) synonyms.  (But it wouldn't be unreasonable to make the tags synonyms because they are closely related.)

Comment: @user4581301 there currently are [10 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1459571/longest-tag-names) with the maximum tag length.

Comment: Why isn't the specific language that throws this error enough that we need a specific tag for the error? How many questions could there be about an error which answer isn't a variation of "your array is either empty or too small"?

Comment: How is this tag a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: What is it for? [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)? [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) (e.g., [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET))? Both? Generic? Can you add some context to your question?

Comment: I think they should *all* get burninated, because they give you almost no info as to what the actual issue is, and usually it's a typo and the OP hasn't actually understood what their code actually does

Comment: @DanielWiddis I'm not sure that there even is a problem. That's why I asked this question in the first place. I would like to know the communities view on such specific tags. And if they are "allowed" or should be avoided.

Comment: @OlegValter well I didn't make a punny title, because this is not a burnination request

Comment: @Lino well, duh :) It was a joke about a waste of a title - if I considered this a burnination request, I'd complain about not following due protocol...

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411059/processing-box2d-begincontact-and-endcontact-error) you linked to that isn't tagged [java] also seems to be about Java, it just isn't tagged as such.

Comment: I think option 1, synonomising, is the obvious thing to do.

Comment: I would go with burning, but people so much like to use tags to tell a story nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with that tag is not that it's too specific. The problem is, that the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is the result of the messy programming, and actually every question with this tag screams to be closed as the duplicate of the canonical question ( [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) is a nice candidate).

So we don't need a tag that means that the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: So you would suggest to burn the tag?

Comment: So... how about [tag:nullpointerexception] and [its canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/2821954)?

Comment: "The issue with that tag is not that it's too specific [...] every question with this tag screams to be closed as the duplicate of the canonical question" a tag that only applies to a single question and its duplicates seems to be extremely specific.